# Using querySelector() to exclude descendent

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm looking to try and do a querySelector for text that avoids picking up a div within the content. Any thoughts gratefully appreciated.

**JS**

```
domdoc.querySelector('li.list_item').textContent
```

**HTML:**

```
<li class="list_item">
  Hello
  <a>
    world,
    <div id="tooltip">
      Please ignore this
    </div>
  </a>
  how are you
</li>
```

Returns:

```
Hello world, Please ignore this how are you
```

Would like to see:

```
Hello world, how are you
```

Answer (score 3):

`querySelector` will select *an element*, not *an element and its descendants*.

`textContent` including descendants of the list item is a feature of `textContent`, not of `querySelector`.

You can clone the list item, remove the div from it, then get the textContent of that.

```js
var li = document.querySelector('li.list_item');
var duplicate = li.cloneNode(true);
duplicate.querySelector("div").remove();
console.log(duplicate.textContent);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="list_item">
    Hello
    <a>
    world,
    <div id="tooltip">
      Please ignore this
    </div>
  </a> how are you
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply `replace` the tooltip text and trim whitespaces.

```js
const text = document.querySelector(`li.list_item`).textContent
const tooltip = document.querySelector(`#tooltip`).textContent
const message = text.replace(tooltip, ``).replace(/\s+/g, ` `).trim()

console.log(message)
```

```html
<li class="list_item">
  Hello
  <a>
    world,
    <div id="tooltip">
      Please ignore this
    </div>
  </a>
  how are you
</li>
```